# How to self print/self publish card game

Tags: game-design, playing-cards, game-development, two-player, print-and-play

Essentially, I'm working on a little card game. It's my big project for the next two months or so. I've already made quite a few digital designs, and this game would involve nothing but cards, and possibly a playing board. This would all be printed out on an A4 size sheet of something. This brings me to my question.

What is the best material to mass print my card game? I'm already willing to pay a local printing service to print my card game maybe 2 or 3 times at first, and I'm willing to spend the money to print it repeatedly. That isn't my problem. My problem is that I have no idea what to use for the cards themselves. Now, this would be a print and play game, but for my own personal use, for local product-in-hand sales, and for recommendations on the online print and play service, I'd like to know what the best material is. I'm thinking something like laminated cardstock, but I'd like to know other's opinions.

Comment: As for the materiel a lot of that would depend on the game itself and how the pieces are used.

Comment: This is a *very* broad question. It's not even clear what you want. If if it's just for a few copies, I was very pleased with the results of [PrinterStudio](https://www.printerstudio.com/) (but I think their prices have greatly increased since I used them). They are hardly the only company doing these kinds of custom print jobs

Comment: Have you ever played a game with cards made from laminated card stock? You want something like grey core cards, printed in a standard size (poker, american, european, mini euro, etc). Rounded corners. Not laminated. "Mass produce" makes me nervous for you. Only a publisher should undertake such an endeavor.